# Ant Design Calendar `onSelect` doesn't work as expected

Tags: reactjs, web, antd

I have a Ant Design Calendar component in my React project -

```
<Calendar
     value={this.state.value}
     fullscreen={false}
     onPanelChange={this._onPanelChange}
     onSelect={this._onSelect}
     disabledDate={(current) => {
     return current && moment().isAfter(current, "day");
     }}
/>
```

and I have the following state -

```
this.state = {
   value: moment(),
   scheduleDate: moment(),
}
```

the `_onSelect` function looks like -

```
 _onSelect = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      value,
      scheduleDate: value,
    });
    this.props.setScheduleDate(this.state.scheduleDate.toDate());
    console.log(this.state.scheduleDate);
  };
```

When the user selects a date (say, 23rd of April, 2021), the `console.log` gives me a date of 22nd April(current default date), 2021. Similarly, when the user selects 24th April, 2021, the `console.log` gives 23rd April, 2021.

It always sets `scheduleDate` to what was selected in the previous step. Any idea what's wrong and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code lies here `this.props.setScheduleDate(this.state.scheduleDate.toDate())` because `setState` is asynchronous. That means the `state` will not get updated as soon as we call `setState`. So, the value which you see in the `console` or `this.props.setScheduleDate` is the previous state value.

Now, there are 2 ways in order to resolve this issue

- Using [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)'s `callback` method which is the second parameter to setState() is an optional callback function that will be executed once setState is completed

```
_onSelect = (value) => {
  this.setState({
    value,
    scheduleDate: value,
  }, () => {
    this.props.setScheduleDate(this.state.scheduleDate.toDate());
    console.log(this.state.scheduleDate);
  });
};
```

- Using the `_onSelect` function's parameter while calling `this.props.setScheduleDate`

```
_onSelect = (value) => {
  this.setState({
    value,
    scheduleDate: value,
  });
  this.props.setScheduleDate(value.toDate());
};
```